# Issue in cocoapod : pod install giving error

Tags: ios, iphone, ruby, dependency-management, cocoapods

This is my podfile

```
   pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.1.0'
```

when i try pod install i am getting

> [!] Pod::Executable pull
>
> U ALPValidator/0.0.1/ALPValidator.podspec
>
> A APAsyncDictionary/0.0.3/APAsyncDictionary.podspec
>
> A ASCScreenBrightnessDetector/0.1.0/ASCScreenBrightnessDetector.podspec
>
> A Appboy-iOS-SDK/2.3.1/Appboy-iOS-SDK.podspec
>
> A AuthorizeNet/0.1.0/AuthorizeNet.podspec
>
> A CTFeedback/1.0.8/CTFeedback.podspec
>
> U CardIO/3.2.2/CardIO.podspec
>
> U CardIO/3.3.0/CardIO.podspec
>
> U CardIO/3.4.1/CardIO.podspec
>
> U CardIO/3.4.4/CardIO.podspec
>
> A Colours/4.1/Colours.podspec
>
> A FXBlurView/1.5.3/FXBlurView.podspec
>
> M Facebook-iOS-SDK/3.9.0/Facebook-iOS-SDK.podspec
>
> A FreeStreamer/1.5.3/FreeStreamer.podspec
>
> A GoldenFleece/1.1/GoldenFleece.podspec
>
> A Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/6.8.0/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK.podspec
>
> A IOSLinkedInAPI/2.0.0/IOSLinkedInAPI.podspec
>
> A JDStatusBarNotification/1.4.7/JDStatusBarNotification.podspec
>
> A JSONJoy/0.1.0/JSONJoy.podspec
>
> A KTBTaskQueue/1.0.0/KTBTaskQueue.podspec
>
> A LINEActivity/0.2.0/LINEActivity.podspec
>
> U LetsMove/1.9/LetsMove.podspec
>
> A LumberjackPrettyClassInformation/1.0.0/LumberjackPrettyClassInformation.podspec
>
> A MSCachedAsyncViewDrawing/1.0.1/MSCachedAsyncViewDrawing.podspec
>
> A MUKAdMobViewController/1.2.1/MUKAdMobViewController.podspec
>
> A MUKAdMobViewController/1.2.2/MUKAdMobViewController.podspec
>
> A MUKAdMobViewController/1.2/MUKAdMobViewController.podspec
>
> A MUKToolkit/1.1.1/MUKToolkit.podspec
>
> A NXOAuth2Client/1.2.5/NXOAuth2Client.podspec
>
> ```
> A PubNub/3.5.5/PubNub.podspec
>
> A RestReaper/0.1.1/RestReaper.podspec
>
> A SatelliteStore/1.0.0/SatelliteStore.podspec
>
> A UIImage+Dummy/0.0.2/UIImage+Dummy.podspec
>
> A WYPopoverController/0.1.8/WYPopoverController.podspec
> Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
>
> Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
>
> as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.
> ```

What is the issue?How can i fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [podfile gives an error on install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474536/podfile-gives-an-error-on-install)

Comment: Pretty sure its a duplicate