# Cocoapods error: "Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files."

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods

When installing a new CocoaPod, I got the following error.

```
$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Pod::Executable pull

A   AFHARchiver/0.2.1/AFHARchiver.podspec

A   AFWunderlist/1.0/AFWunderlist.podspec

A   AFWunderlist/1.1/AFWunderlist.podspec

A   AFgzipRequestSerializer/0.0.1/AFgzipRequestSerializer.podspec
```

.
  .
  .

```
A   wpxmlrpc/0.4/wpxmlrpc.podspec

A   zipzap/6.0/zipzap.podspec
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.

Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use `'git add/rm <file>'`

as appropriate to mark resolution, or use `'git commit -a'`.
```

Thought I would share the fix below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CocoaPods - pod setup Failed: /usr/bin/git checkout master](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825715/cocoapods-pod-setup-failed-usr-bin-git-checkout-master)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Problem was with specs repository, not on my side.

Found the answer here [podfile gives an error on install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474536/podfile-gives-an-error-on-install),  but since the question was less explicit on the symptom, I thought I would cross-reference it again in case someone was looking it up differently.

The answer is in the blog post here http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/ which explains the issue and the fix which is repeated below:

"You are going to have to manually delete any local copies of the Specs repository and re-clone the new version of the Specs repository. You can do that with the following commands:

```
  $ pod repo remove master
  $ pod setup
```

If you have any local commits or changes to the Specs repository which are not merged, you should ensure you have a copy of them. I would recommend that you manually copy these changes over and re-commit them. You can fix your repository without deleting, however, this is not a simple process, so we are instead recommending that you delete your copy of the Specs repository and any forks of it."

Comment: This answer would be even better if you copied the fix from the blog post and put it here. Just in case that blog ever goes down, someone reading this answer will have the information available no matter what.

Comment: When it says delete any local specs repository, what does this mean/path point to? or does running the commands cover this?

Comment: Yes, the commands delete the local specs repository.. If you have not read the complete blog.  I would recommend it.  If gives the answer more context.

Comment: My goodness...THANK YOU! I was spending hours trying to figure this out then finally decided that maybe someone had the same problem. THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!

Comment: this also fixes this stupid error: 'An error occurred while performing `git pull` on repo `master`.'

Answer (score 15):

`rm -rf ~/.cocoapods` also works