# pod install listing a ton of pods not in my podfile

Tags: xcode, git, cocoapods

I have a clean git working directory and I am trying to do a pod install for a new library I want and this is what I get:

```
MacBook-Pro:rcoredata Me$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Pod::Executable pull

A   AFHARchiver/0.2.1/AFHARchiver.podspec

A   AFWunderlist/1.0/AFWunderlist.podspec

A   AFWunderlist/1.1/AFWunderlist.podspec

A   ALPValidator/0.0.1/ALPValidator.podspec

A   AMTagListView/0.2.1/AMTagListView.podspec

A   AMTagListView/0.2/AMTagListView.podspec

A   APAsyncDictionary/0.0.3/APAsyncDictionary.podspec

A   APSmartStorage/0.0.5/APSmartStorage.podspec

A   ASCScreenBrightnessDetector/0.1.0/ASCScreenBrightnessDetector.podspec

A   AdPopcornSDK/3.0.8/AdPopcornSDK.podspec

A   AlertShortkut/1.0/AlertShortkut.podspec

A   Appboy-iOS-SDK/2.3.1/Appboy-iOS-SDK.podspec

A   Apptimize/1.5.8/Apptimize.podspec

A   AuthorizeNet/0.1.0/AuthorizeNet.podspec

A   Binding/1.0.0/Binding.podspec

A   Binding/1.1.0/Binding.podspec

A   BloodMagic/0.5.2/BloodMagic.podspec

A   Bolts/1.0.0/Bolts.podspec

A   BugSense/3.6/BugSense.podspec

A   BugshotKit/0.1.0/BugshotKit.podspec

A   CCHMapClusterController/1.4.0/CCHMapClusterController.podspec

A   CKStringUtils/1.1.1/CKStringUtils.podspec

A   CKStringUtils/1.1.2/CKStringUtils.podspec

A   CMHTMLView/0.3.0/CMHTMLView.podspec

A   CNXML/0.0.6/CNXML.podspec

A   CTFeedback/1.0.8/CTFeedback.podspec

A   CaptainPass/1.0.0/CaptainPass.podspec

A   CaptainPass/1.0.1/CaptainPass.podspec

U   CardIO/3.2.2/CardIO.podspec

U   CardIO/3.2.3/CardIO.podspec

U   CardIO/3.3.0/CardIO.podspec

U   CardIO/3.4.1/CardIO.podspec

U   CardIO/3.4.4/CardIO.podspec

A   CargoBay/2.0.2/CargoBay.podspec

A   Cedar/0.9.5/Cedar.podspec

A   ClearBlade-iOS-API/0.9.2.2/ClearBlade-iOS-API.podspec

A   Cocoa-Touch-Barcodes/0.0.1/Cocoa-Touch-Barcodes.podspec

U   CocoaSPDY/1.0.0/CocoaSPDY.podspec

A   Colours/4.1/Colours.podspec

A   CoreParse@siuying/1.1.0.20140123/CoreParse@siuying.podspec

M   CorePlot/1.0/CorePlot.podspec

M   CorePlot/1.1/CorePlot.podspec

M   CorePlot/1.2/CorePlot.podspec

M   CorePlot/1.3/CorePlot.podspec

M   CorePlot/1.4/CorePlot.podspec

U   Countly/2.0.0/Countly.podspec

A   DBCamera/0.1/DBCamera.podspec

A   DCOAboutWindow/0.0.1/DCOAboutWindow.podspec

A   DCOTransparentScroller/0.0.1/DCOTransparentScroller.podspec

A   DCTextEngine/0.1.0/DCTextEngine.podspec

A   DUIToolbox/0.1.1/DUIToolbox.podspec

A   DUIToolbox/0.2.2/DUIToolbox.podspec

A   EmpatikaBeacons/0.0.4/EmpatikaBeacons.podspec

A   Ensembles/0.3.0/Ensembles.podspec

A   EstimoteSDK/1.3.0/EstimoteSDK.podspec

M   FMDB/2.0/FMDB.podspec

A   FTFoundation/2.0.0/FTFoundation.podspec

A   FTUIKit/2.0.0/FTUIKit.podspec

A   FXBlurView/1.5.2/FXBlurView.podspec

A   FXBlurView/1.5.3/FXBlurView.podspec

A   FXKeychain/1.5/FXKeychain.podspec

M   Facebook-iOS-SDK/3.9.0/Facebook-iOS-SDK.podspec

A   FastSocket/1.2/FastSocket.podspec

A   Firebase/1.1.2/Firebase.podspec

A   FlatUI/0.1.0/FlatUI.podspec

A   FlatUIKit/1.3/FlatUIKit.podspec

A   FreeStreamer/1.5.3/FreeStreamer.podspec

A   GCDWebServer/1.2.1/GCDWebServer.podspec

A   GCDWebServer/1.2.2/GCDWebServer.podspec

A   GHUnit/0.5.9/GHUnit.podspec

A   GRMustache/6.9.1/GRMustache.podspec

A   GVUserDefaults/0.9.4/GVUserDefaults.podspec

A   GlitchKit/0.0.3/GlitchKit.podspec

A   GoldenFleece/1.1/GoldenFleece.podspec

A   Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/6.8.0/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK.podspec

A   GoogleMediaFramework/0.1.2/GoogleMediaFramework.podspec

A   Helpshift/4.2.0/Helpshift.podspec

A   Heyzap/6.2.2/Heyzap.podspec

A   Heyzap/6.2.4/Heyzap.podspec

A   HysteriaPlayer/1.5.3/HysteriaPlayer.podspec

A   IMQuickSearch/0.3/IMQuickSearch.podspec

A   IOSLinkedInAPI/2.0.0/IOSLinkedInAPI.podspec

A   InstagramKit/1.1.0/InstagramKit.podspec

A   JDStatusBarNotification/1.4.7/JDStatusBarNotification.podspec

A   JFOpenWeatherMapManager/1.0.0/JFOpenWeatherMapManager.podspec

A   JSONJoy/0.1.0/JSONJoy.podspec

A   JavaScriptBridge/0.1.1/JavaScriptBridge.podspec

A   JavaScriptBridge/0.1.2/JavaScriptBridge.podspec

A   JavaScriptBridge/0.1.3/JavaScriptBridge.podspec

A   JustType/0.2.0/JustType.podspec

U   KSCrash/0.0.2/KSCrash.podspec

A   KTBTaskQueue/1.0.0/KTBTaskQueue.podspec

A   LINEActivity/0.2.0/LINEActivity.podspec

A   LINQ4Obj-C/1.1.0/LINQ4Obj-C.podspec

A   LTHMonthYearPickerView/1.0.0/LTHMonthYearPickerView.podspec

A   LazyProperty/1.0.0/LazyProperty.podspec

U   LetsMove/1.9/LetsMove.podspec

A   LumberjackPrettyClassInformation/1.0.0/LumberjackPrettyClassInformation.podspec

A   M13CSVParser/1.0.0/M13CSVParser.podspec

A   M13Checkbox/1.0.0/M13Checkbox.podspec

A   M13InfiniteTabBar/2.0.1/M13InfiniteTabBar.podspec

A   MCSwipeTableViewCell/2.1.0/MCSwipeTableViewCell.podspec

A   MKFoundationKit/1.1.0/MKFoundationKit.podspec

A   MKPolygon-GPC/0.0.1/MKPolygon-GPC.podspec

A   MMDrawerController/0.5.2/MMDrawerController.podspec

A   MSCachedAsyncViewDrawing/1.0.1/MSCachedAsyncViewDrawing.podspec

A   MUKAdMobViewController/1.2.1/MUKAdMobViewController.podspec

A   MUKAdMobViewController/1.2.2/MUKAdMobViewController.podspec

A   MUKAdMobViewController/1.2/MUKAdMobViewController.podspec

A   MUKToolkit/1.1.1/MUKToolkit.podspec

A   MZRSlideInMenu/0.0.2/MZRSlideInMenu.podspec

A   Malcom/2.0.11/Malcom.podspec

U   MapBox/1.1.0/MapBox.podspec

A   Mixpanel/2.0.5/Mixpanel.podspec

A   Mixpanel/2.3.1/Mixpanel.podspec

A   MobileDeepLinking-iOS/0.1.0/MobileDeepLinking-iOS.podspec

A   MobileDeepLinking-iOS/0.1.1/MobileDeepLinking-iOS.podspec

A   MultibyteDescription/0.2/MultibyteDescription.podspec

A   NAKPlaybackIndicatorView/0.0.1/NAKPlaybackIndicatorView.podspec

A   NAKPlaybackIndicatorView/0.0.2/NAKPlaybackIndicatorView.podspec

A   NCICharts/1.0.0/NCICharts.podspec

A   NCICharts/1.0.1/NCICharts.podspec

A   NSObjectProperties/0.0.3/NSObjectProperties.podspec

A   NSOrderedDictionary/1.0.0/NSOrderedDictionary.podspec

A   NSOrderedDictionary/1.0.1/NSOrderedDictionary.podspec

A   NXOAuth2Client/1.2.5/NXOAuth2Client.podspec

A   OCBorghettiView/0.0.5/OCBorghettiView.podspec

A   OpenSSL-Universal/1.0.1.f/OpenSSL-Universal.podspec

A   PACScrollView/1.0/PACScrollView.podspec

A   PPLogger/0.1.0/PPLogger.podspec

A   PPTopSlideMenu/0.1.0/PPTopSlideMenu.podspec

A   PSPDFKit/3.4.6/PSPDFKit.podspec

A   PayMillSDK/1.1.0/PayMillSDK.podspec

U   ProximityKit/0.2.3/ProximityKit.podspec

U   ProximityKit/0.2.6/ProximityKit.podspec

A   PubNub/3.5.5/PubNub.podspec

A   RDVCalendarView/1.0.3/RDVCalendarView.podspec

A   RDVCalendarView/1.0.4/RDVCalendarView.podspec

A   RDVTabBarController/1.1.3/RDVTabBarController.podspec

M   README.md

A   RPDynamicWarningView/1.0/RPDynamicWarningView.podspec

A   RestReaper/0.1.0/RestReaper.podspec

A   RestReaper/0.1.1/RestReaper.podspec

A   SAMCache/0.2.1/SAMCache.podspec

A   SDCAlertView/1.0/SDCAlertView.podspec

A   SLObjectiveCRuntimeAdditions/1.1.1/SLObjectiveCRuntimeAdditions.podspec

A   SLObjectiveCRuntimeAdditions/1.1.2/SLObjectiveCRuntimeAdditions.podspec

A   SLRESTfulCoreData/1.5.2/SLRESTfulCoreData.podspec

A   STPTransitions/0.0.2/STPTransitions.podspec

A   STTweetLabel/3.1.5/STTweetLabel.podspec

A   SVBlurView/0.0.1/SVBlurView.podspec

A   SZTextView/1.1.1/SZTextView.podspec

A   SatelliteStore/1.0.0/SatelliteStore.podspec

A   ScanditSDK/3.2.3/ScanditSDK.podspec

A   SimpleObjectPool/0.1/SimpleObjectPool.podspec

A   SparkInspector/1.1.2/SparkInspector.podspec

A   SpinningDiskView/0.0.1/SpinningDiskView.podspec

A   StandardPaths/1.5.6/StandardPaths.podspec

A   StreamingKit/0.0.17/StreamingKit.podspec

A   StreamingKit/0.1.18/StreamingKit.podspec

A   StreamingKit/0.1.19/StreamingKit.podspec

A   StudyplusSDK/1.1.0/StudyplusSDK.podspec

A   SwipeView/1.3/SwipeView.podspec

A   TCButton/1.0.0/TCButton.podspec

A   TDBadgedCell/2.5.1/TDBadgedCell.podspec

A   TLIndexPathTools/0.2.1/TLIndexPathTools.podspec

A   TWTSideMenuViewController/0.3/TWTSideMenuViewController.podspec

A   TWTToast/0.2/TWTToast.podspec

A   Taplytics/1.1.0/Taplytics.podspec

A   Taplytics/1.1.2/Taplytics.podspec

A   Taplytics/1.1.4/Taplytics.podspec

A   Typhoon/1.7.3/Typhoon.podspec

A   Typhoon/1.7.4/Typhoon.podspec

A   Typhoon/1.7.5/Typhoon.podspec

A   Typhoon/1.7.6/Typhoon.podspec

A   Typhoon/1.7.7/Typhoon.podspec

A   UCKDeviceInfo/0.0.1/UCKDeviceInfo.podspec

A   UIColor+PerceivedLuminance/1/UIColor+PerceivedLuminance.podspec

A   UICustomizeKit/0.1.0/UICustomizeKit.podspec

A   UIImage+AverageColor/1/UIImage+AverageColor.podspec

A   UIImage+Dummy/0.0.2/UIImage+Dummy.podspec

A   UIImage+ImageWithColor/1/UIImage+ImageWithColor.podspec

A   UITextSubClass/0.0.6/UITextSubClass.podspec

A   URLMock/1.1/URLMock.podspec

A   VK-ios-sdk/1.0.6/VK-ios-sdk.podspec

A   VTAcknowledgementsViewController/0.8/VTAcknowledgementsViewController.podspec

A   WJHXCTest/0.0.2/WJHXCTest.podspec

A   WMGaugeView/0.0.1/WMGaugeView.podspec

A   WYPopoverController/0.1.8/WYPopoverController.podspec

A   YISplashScreen/1.2.1/YISplashScreen.podspec

A   YandexMobileMetrica/1.2.0/YandexMobileMetrica.podspec

A   ZumeroSync/1.1.0.1729/ZumeroSync.podspec

A   box-ios-sdk-v2-metadata/0.4.0/box-ios-sdk-v2-metadata.podspec

A   google-cast-sdk/2.0/google-cast-sdk.podspec

A   libHN/1.1.0/libHN.podspec

A   libzmq/4.0.3/libzmq.podspec

A   notificare-push-lib/1.0-RC6/notificare-push-lib.podspec

A   sonos-objc/0.1.1/sonos-objc.podspec

A   uidevice-extension/0.0.3/uidevice-extension.podspec

A   wpxmlrpc/0.4/wpxmlrpc.podspec

A   ym/1.2.6/ym.podspec

A   zipzap/6.0/zipzap.podspec
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.

Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'

as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.

MacBook-Pro:rcoredata Me$
```

Here is my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '6.1'
pod 'SIAlertView', :git => 'git@github.com:Sumi-Interactive/SIAlertView.git'
pod 'WEPopover', '~> 0.0.1'
pod 'TestFlightSDK', '~> 2.0.2'
pod 'JVFloatLabeledTextField', '~> 0.0.1'
pod 'BButton',  :git => 'https://github.com/jessesquires/BButton.git'
pod 'DDPopoverBackgroundView', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'BSKeyboardControls', '~> 2.0'
pod 'CardIO', '~> 3.4.3'
pod 'RATreeView', '~> 0.1.5'
pod 'T1Autograph', '~> 1.5.5'
```

Not sure why this started happening, this worked perfectly until I added the last line in my podfile.  None of the pods listed are required for any of the pods in my podfile.  Now I can't even remove that pod and do `pod install`

Anyone run into this before?

Comment: Have you read the CocoaPods site message: [Repairing Our Broken Specs Repository](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/).

Comment: no - thank you!  Make this an answer so I can accept it

Comment: possible duplicate of [When installing a new Cocoapod I got the error "Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534309/when-installing-a-new-cocoapod-i-got-the-error-pull-is-not-possible-because-you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read the CocoaPods site message: [Repairing Our Broken Specs Repository](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/).

From the CocoaPods site:

> Well, basically your CocoaPods setup is going to break. You are going
>   to have to manually delete any local copies of the Specs repository
>   and re-clone the new version of the Specs repository. ...

See the site for details.