# iPhone : Error in installing cocoapods into project

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods

**I have pod files that need to install for the sample project. But once i fire pod install command into terminal i got following error:**

```
 [!] Pod::Executable pull

    A   AAShareBubbles/1.0.2/AAShareBubbles.podspec

    A   ABContactHelper/0.1/ABContactHelper.podspec

    A   ABPadLockScreen/3.0.0/ABPadLockScreen.podspec

    A   ABPadLockScreen/3.0.1/ABPadLockScreen.podspec

    A   ACReuseQueue/0.0.1/ACReuseQueue.podspec

    ......

    Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.

    Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'

    as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.

**Can anyone guide me what is this about and how can i remove that.**
```

Comment: are you trying to install pod at root directory of you project?

Comment: @freenalcer : Yes from the directory having Podfile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [podfile gives an error on install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474536/podfile-gives-an-error-on-install)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this thread](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/).

They messed something up with cocoa pods recently, so you need to run the following commands:

```
$ pod repo remove master
$ pod setup
```